# better way to handle the below code

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private bool CheckMemberCountry(string country)
{
    string[] countries = new string[] { "AF", "BD", "CA", "IN", "IR", "RO", "AN", "CY", "IL", "PH" };
    foreach (string memberCountry in countries)
    {
        if (memberCountry.Equals(country))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I dont want to hard code the values like above, how can I handle it

Comment: What is exactly the question? is the code doesn't work?

Comment: why you people dont use collection  List<string> ls =new List<string>(); ls.add and then loop

Comment: If I dont want to hardcode these values of countries how else can I handle it in code ?

Comment: If you don't want to hard code those values (because you expect them to change and don't want to edit your code every time they do) you would need to import them from an outside source then loop through them. An outside source such as a file or a database.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest way would be to re-write it as one line, but it is not the most efficient:

```
return (new string[] { "AF", "BD", "CA", "IN", "IR", "RO", "AN", "CY", "IL", "PH" })
    .Contains(country);
```

You should make the array a static readonly variable, and use it in your function:

```
private static readonly string[] AllCountries = new string[] {
    "AF", "BD", "CA", "IN", "IR", "RO", "AN", "CY", "IL", "PH"
};

private bool CheckMemberCountry(string country) {
    return AllCountries.Contains(country);
}
```

Comment: If I dont want to hardcode these values of countries how else can I handle it in code ?

Comment: @Vidya If you do not want to hardcode them, you can assign `AllCountries` from whatever source the non-hardcoded values should be coming from. The best place to do it would be a static constructor of your containing class.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
static string[] Countries = new string[] { "AF", "BD", "CA", "IN", "IR", "RO", "AN", "CY", "IL", "PH" };    

private bool CheckMemberCountry(string country)
{       
   return Countries.Contains(country);
}
```

Comment: nice and simple, but I would recommend the countries array being declared as a static global

Comment: If I dont want to hardcode these values of countries how else can I handle it in code ?

Comment: @Vidya: If your question is to avoid hard coding you should really write that in your post, click edit and add some more information

Answer (score 1):

If the list of countries is unlikely to change, you can do something like this:

```
// note: sorted alphabetically
private static readonly string[] countries =  new string[] { 
  "AF", "AN", "BD", "CA", "CY", "IL",
  "IN", "IR", "PH", "RO" }; 

private bool CheckMemberCountry(string country)
{
    return Array.BinarySearch<string>(countries, country) >= 0;
}
```

If the countries do change, you may want to put them in a configuration file.  Your App.config file might resemble:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
     <add key="countries" value="AF,BD,CA,IN,IR,RO,AN,CY,IL,PH"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And in the above code, you could replace the line:

```
private static readonly string[] countries =  new string[] {
       "AF", "AN", "BD", "CA", "CY", "IL",
       "IN", "IR", "PH", "RO" };
```

With (include a reference to System.Configuration.dll, and include System.Configuration in your Usings):

```
using System.Configuration;

// ...

private static readonly string[] countries =  ConfigurationManager
    .AppSettings["countries"] // configuration setting with key "countries"
    .Split(',') // split comma-delimited values
    .Select(a=>a.Trim()) // trim each value (remove whitespace)
    .OrderBy(a=>a) // sort list (for binary search)
    .ToArray(); // convert to array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool CheckMemberCountry(string country)
{
   return new string[] { "AF", "BD", "CA", "IN", "IR", "RO", "AN", "CY", "IL", "PH" }.Contains(country);
}
```